# grid inside android listview?

Tags: android, listview, grid

I have a list that contains a set of numbers that need to be shown in a grid...
I got this functionality by using linearlayouts 3rows and put 7 textviews in each so this gives me a 3x7 matrix...

I did this because the gridview can't be positioned in a listview...

this works fine so far but on smaller screens where the listview actually needs to scroll...

the app crashes on scroll

```
            for(int y=0; y<3; y++){
                    for(int x=0; x<7; x++){
                        if(counter < resultList.size()){
                            tmp = ((TextView)((LinearLayout) resultGrid.getChildAt(y)).getChildAt(x));
                            tmp.setText(resultList.get(counter).toString());
                            tmp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

that's the code I use to populate the grid....

any ideas on what could be causing tha crash? when the grid isn't populated it scrolls just fine...

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.